# How to hide and display an icon in a bootstrap collapsable panel with CSS only

Tags: html, css

So, I'm using Bootstrap's collapsable panel thing (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/) and I want my font awesome icons (+ / -) to show up correspondingly, when the panel is collapsed or not.

I am not an expert on using CSS for these type of things, but I'm sure there's gotta be a way...

Here's the HTML:

```
 <section class="disciplines">
        <div class="disciplines-collapsable">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-oggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-1" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-2" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-2">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-3" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-3">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-4" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-4">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-5" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-5">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-6" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-6">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-7" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-7">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-8" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-8">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-9" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-9">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseExample-10" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-10">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                richardson ad
                                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                                sapiente ea proident.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Go inspect the button element via your browser dev tools, and watch how its classes change, when you open/close the element. After that, you should have an idea on what you can use for your selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

https://jsfiddle.net/8acj9for/5/

It's not utilised but it's useful for your case

I created 2 buttons (+ button and - button)

- When you click on `+`, UI will add `d-node` class to `+` (to hide `+`) and then remove `d-node` class from `-` (to show `-`)
- When you click on `-`, UI will add `d-node` class to `-` (to hide `-`) and then remove `d-node` class from `+` (to show `+`)

Beyond that, I add `.collapse('show')` for `+`, and `.collapse('hide')` for `-` to avoid unexpected collapsation behaviour.

You can check the code snippet here too

```
<section class="disciplines">
  <div class="disciplines-collapsable">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="(function() { $('#collapseExample-1').collapse('show'); $('#collapseExample-1-button-plus').addClass('d-none'); $('#collapseExample-1-button-minus').removeClass('d-none'); })()" id="collapseExample-1-button-plus">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary d-none" type="button" onclick="(function() { $('#collapseExample-1').collapse('hide'); $('#collapseExample-1-button-plus').removeClass('d-none'); $('#collapseExample-1-button-minus').addClass('d-none'); })()" id="collapseExample-1-button-minus">
              <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </p>
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">
            <div class="card card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
              richardson ad
              squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
              sapiente ea proident.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```